# connect subgraphs in optimal way

Tags: optimization, connectivity, subgraph, disjoint-sets

How can i connect two graphs by a bridge(link) in an optimal way?

There are some criteria such as weight of each link, stability of link (connection quality), expected time for connection, etc. I am wondering how I can define a cost function based on them?  In other words, how can I quantify the above criteria?

Any article or lecture note would help a lot.

Comment: What is the definition of optimal in this scenario?

Comment: Optimal:= optimize defined cost-function for objects that said above